# plot on timeline x-axis without year -chart.js

Tags: charts

I would like to plot a cumulative total per day with chart.js. Per each season (October to September) the plot just have one line.

The data that should be plotted by chart.js is available in a postgres table in a structure like this:

```
date        season  cum_sum
2021-12-23  2022    11
2022-01-01  2022    19
2022-01-04  2022    20
2022-01-05  2022    40 
2022-03-01  2022    43
2022-12-01  2023    3
2022-12-02  2023    7
2022-12-10  2023    11
2022-12-23  2023    17
2023-01-01  2023    19
2023-01-05  2023    30
```

So far the x-axis is not chronological. Days of the season 2023, that were not part of the season 2022, are plotted at the end of the x-axis. E.g.: data_2022 = ["01-03", 5], ["01-10", 15] data_2023 = ["01-03", 10], ["01-05",20] --> 01/05 is plotted on the end of the x-axis. Furthermore the months Oct to Dez are displayed on the end of the x-axis, whereas this have to be the first months on the x-axis, as the season starts with Oct. How can I solve this?
[image: chart]

Here the current JS-Code:

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
        // retrieve data from PHP as JSON object using fetch API
        fetch('./inc/get_data.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(baseData  => {
            const data_2022 = baseData['2022'].map(arr => ({ x: arr[0], y: parseFloat(arr[1])}));
            const data_2023 = baseData['2023'].map(arr => ({ x: arr[0], y: parseFloat(arr[1])}));
            // create chart
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Season 2022',
                    data: data_2022,
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                    fill: false 
                    }, {
                    label: 'Season 2023',
                    data: data_2023,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    fill: false
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'day',
                            unitStepSize: 1,
                            displayFormats: {
                                'day': 'MMM DD'
                            },
                            tooltipFormat: 'MM-DD',
                        }
                    }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
                }
            }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
```

Comment: The x-axis seems to be working as a category one, not a time axis. Transform the x values to timestamps (e.g., `x: Date.parse(arr[0])` or `x: new Date(arr[0]).valueOf()` - you may even add a fictitious year to the string arr[0] to make parsing safer) and we can work from there.

Comment: All x-values are 0 now. Getting the error: 'Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes' (and yAxes)

Comment: I didn't notice the `xAxes` and `yAxes` ... these were used with previous versions of charts.js; for newer versions just use `x`, `y`, pointing to onr configuration object (and then an `y2` and so on if you need a secondary y axis). Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr24xd6k/1/) and please fork it or create something similar if it still doesn't work out as you want it. Good luck!